# What do I need to modify from the default squid.conf to make it work as a transparent proxy server?

Tags: squid

I have a router with DD-WRT and forwarding from the router seems to work with the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
PROXY_IP=192.168.77.77
PROXY_PORT=3128
LAN_IP=`nvram get lan_ipaddr`
LAN_NET=$LAN_IP/`nvram get lan_netmask`

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -s $LAN_NET -d $LAN_NET -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -s ! $PROXY_IP -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to $PROXY_IP:$PROXY_PORT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o br0 -s $LAN_NET -d $PROXY_IP -p tcp -j SNAT --to $LAN_IP
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -s $LAN_NET -d $PROXY_IP -p tcp --dport $PROXY_PORT -j ACCEPT
```

Now if I just run the default `squid.conf` file, I get the following page on my web broweser:

```
ERROR
The requested URL could not be retrieved
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: /questions/ask

Invalid URL
```

As you can see, 'stackoverflow.com' is truncated from the URL: stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Now if I change append `transparent` to the following line:

```
http_port 3128 -> http_port 3128 transparent
```

None of the pages show up in the web browser and I get the following error in '`/var/log/squid/cache.log':

```
 NF getsockopt(SO_ORIGINAL_DST) failed on local=192.168.77.77:3128 remote=192.168.77.1:5268 FD 9 flags=33: (92) Protocol not available
```

Is there anyway for me to make squid work? No reference on google.com seems to help.

Answer (score -1):

By default Squid will deny all access. You have to specify who is allowed.

Add this to your acl list

```
acl mycomputer src <yourip>
```

Then add this right before the deny all

```
http_access allow mycomputer

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all
```

Before adding that to the squid.conf, I was also getting the same or similar error.

Comment: it has been some time since I have touched squid. I have done what you have suggested and more... but I still could not get squid to work.

Comment: First, what version do you have installed? Second, are you sure it installed correctly? Were there any errors during install? If you're not tied to your current install, backup your conf, remove squid and install again using the latest. I actually installed the 3.4 which is beta, but working just fine. The conf file is also not as loaded as previous versions. Let me know.

Comment: If using CentOS, see this page to install 3.4: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/KnowledgeBase/CentOS